# Dynamic Paint and Wave modifier looks different in the Render and Viewport

Tags: rendering, modifiers, physics

I have this animation of a coin falling into a smartphone's screen / water, and creating ripples as visible below in this viewport screenshot:

[image]

The ripples on the surface are a mix of Dynamic Paint and Wave Modifier (based on a Gleb Alexandrov tutorial).

When I render, the ripples disappear:

[image]

What causes this?

[image]

Comment: Weird, i tested your file, changing nothing. I rendered multiple times and for first ones some frames didn't have any waves, while later re-renders worked perfectly (I deleted cache before every render)... _Me do not like that_.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.90 - any clues as why this is happening? Will try with the latest version now that I've just downloaded.

Comment: found that https://developer.blender.org/T59997 about 2.8, but i tested in 2.9 and found that it is also happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic paint apparently needs baking to work in render in 2.9.

[image: cache DP tap]

Baked simulation:

[image: Baked simulation]

Here: https://developer.blender.org/T59997  the issue is pointed in Blender 2.8, but it still marked as a known issue.

**Edit:**

Adding here that in 3.0 there is no need to bake.